# Why is BlockingQueue used for SingleThreadExecutor?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

SingleThreadExecutor creates just one thread. You need BlockingQueue when multiple threads deal with that queue. Why use BlockingQueue then? Where is the second thread?

ThreadPoolExecutor has a BlockingQueue as a parameter.

```
public static ExecutorService newSingleThreadExecutor() {
    return new FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService
        (new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1,
                                0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()));
}
```

Comment: As many threads as you want submit tasks to the executor. These tasks are stored in a queue, and executed one by one by a single thread in the executor.

Comment: a simple queue would have sufficed, why do you need mutual exclusion for it?

Comment: Why does a "simple queue" suffice with multiple producers?

Comment: "simple queue" does not suffice for multiple producers. how does producing thread 2 get to know if storage is full after producing thread 1 putting in some values? For that you ought to have a blocking queue.

Comment: Also, it needs to be a _blocking_ queue because that's how the worker thread awaits new tasks. It calls `q.take()` and the call does not return (i.e., it _blocks_) until there is at least one task in the queue to be taken.

Comment: you mean that the tasks being added is one operation - done by one thread, while executing the tasks is done by another thread - object returned by newSingleThreadExecutor? Hence is the use of BlockingQueue?

Comment: "tasks being added is one operation - done by one thread, while executing the tasks is done by another thread" 
Yes. Even in the "simplest" case where you only have one producer and one consumer you will need some level of protection. 
Moreover, as Solomon pointed out, the single worker thread relies on the blocking mechanism of the Queue to "wait" until something is submitted.